How to add environmental path PYTHONHOME and dll search path in vcxproj file in visual studio c++ project?
I know that for the two I could just simply copy the dll to x64\XXX folder, and I can add PYTHONHOME  PATH in the debug environment under project setting.
However, there is a con to those for me because the project would be shared among others via TFS.
What I want:

hard set dll search path in project setting, so when running program will also search those path for dll.

Set Path variable PYTHONHOME and its path not in debugging environment, but somewhere in project setting such that PYTHONHOME Path setting will be hardset in the vcxproj file.


A clear direction on how to do this?

According to @ogggre's answer： msbuild, how to set environment variables?, I tested it and share it with you.
First, you can define a task in the vcxproj file using the UsingTask element. (Used to set environment variables during the build process)
<UsingTask
TaskName="SetEnvironmentVariableTask"
 TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v$(MSBuildToolsVersion).dll">
 
 <ParameterGroup>
   <Name ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
   <Value ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
 </ParameterGroup>
 
 <Task>
   <Using Namespace="System" />
   <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
     <![CDATA[
      Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(Name, Value);
     ]]>
   </Code>
 </Task>
 
</UsingTask>

In MSBuild 14+, AssemblyFile references should be:
AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll"

After defining the task, we can call it in the target to use,
<Target Name="SampleTarget" BeforeTargets="Build">
 <SetEnvironmentVariableTask Name="TEST_ENV_VAR" Value="$(MSBuildProjectName)" />
</Target>


do you mean to run command line code before program execution?

There is no need to run command line code manually. This method simply uses a custom task () of MSBuild in the vcxproj file to automatically set environment variables during the build process. All settings are done automatically. In this way, when the project is shared through TFS, these settings will also be preserved with the project.
